# A phrase around "I give up" that is closest to sacrifice

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

A non profit organization is running a campaign that is encouraging people to sacrifice a small luxury and donate that money to a cause instead. They are building the campaign around Twitter hashtag #IGiveUp.

In general, I've seen "I give up" being used as "cease making an effort; admit defeat. (Google)".

Question: Is #IGiveUp an appropriate hashtag in this context? If not, any suggestions on what would be (Around #IGiveUp)?

Comment: Is this nonprofit looking to support a *specific* cause? Or do they just want people to select a cause and donate to it?

Comment: As a marketing slogan it's terrible.  it suggests "I surrender", not "I sacrifice for the greater good".

Comment: Shoulda gone with `#IGive`, but perhaps it was taken...

Comment: @ruakh they work for a specific cause and they are requesting people to donate for that.

Answer (score 3):

You're quite right about the problem with `#IGiveUp`. It's kind of a clever pun (if intentional), but the problem is that "I give up" has such negative connotations — and is such a plausible hashtag on its own — that it overwhelms the cleverness.

As an alternative, I'd suggest `#GiveItUpForACause`. This is also a pun — "give it up for X" is a colloquialism meaning "please clap now for X" — but it has *positive* connotations, and it invites the reader to look deeper to see what is meant.

Comment: Your suggestion for a hashtag is **much** better than the one they're using.

Answer (score 2):

> What are you going to give up for Lent

is a question Catholics commonly ask each other. Often it is something like chocolate or ice cream.

Thus the **#IgiveUp** is appropriate in your context. *I give up* will resonate with one billion Catholics and people who have Catholic friends.  Giving the money spent daily on these treats to a charity will add up.

From [Pope Francis’ Guide to Lent: What You Should Give Up This Year](http://time.com/3714056/pope-francis-lent-2015-fasting/), by Christopher Hale (Feb. 2015)

> “What are you giving up for Lent?” It’s a question a lot of people
>   will get these next few days. If you want to change your body, perhaps
>   alcohol and candy is the way to go. But if you want to change your
>   heart, a harder fast is needed. This narrow road is gritty, but it
>   isn’t sterile.

Comment: The problem is that no one ever says, "I give up for Lent". Instead, they say "I'm giving up ____ for Lent". So the hashtag #IGiveUp doesn't evoke Lent, it evokes surrender.

Answer (score 1):

Since the hashtag **#IGiveUp** doesn't have an object associated with the verb, it does make it sound like the intransitive sense of "give up," which [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/give%20up) defines as

> to cease doing or attempting something especially as an admission of defeat

M-W gives no other intransitive meaning for "give up." Because there is no other intransitive meaning, the hashtag necessarily imparts a sense of surrender, rather than sacrifice. The only way to "fix" the hashtag would be to include an object:

> #IGiveThingsUp

which sounds lame, but "things" is just a placeholder here.

The object could also be placed last:

> #IGiveUpLuxury

The issue with adding the object is that the hashtag then becomes more specific; however, without the object it definitely conveys the meaning of "surrender."

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
#IGive(Up)
```

To make things clearer